# URI definition with <%@ Page import = ...%> does not reload properly with mvnDebug tomcat:run

Tags: jsp, maven, tomcat

In a web application project, I am using the @Page import in the jsp to load the URIs definition.

```
<%@page import="org.springframework.social.quickstart.config.Uris"%>
```

The Uris.java file contains only public static final strings.
However, when I modify it and then do an mvn tomcat:run or mvnDebug tomcat:run, the web application does not take into account the modified Uris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I had started the project by cloning an other one and kept the same package names.

Doing an mvn clean install before the mvn tomcat:run solves the problem.

Probably due to my lack of understanding of the jsp technology and how it interacts with tomcat. Comments welcomed if you have a more precise explanation and best practises guidelines.